# send mail with attachment using phpmailer and html form

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

i am trying to send mail from one to other using gmail smtp.
the mail sent successfully but without attachment. how can i solve this?

html form:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form"  method="post" action="sendresume.PHP" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Mobile number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                        </div>

                        <p class="lead" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Resume :</p>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" required="required" >
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">

                        <textarea name="messege" id="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Note"></textarea>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
```

and php code is:

```
<?php
include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
$email = $_POST["email"];
$messege=$_POST['messege'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom("feedback@abc.com");
$mail->Subject = "this is subject";
$mail->Body = "this is body <br/><br/><br/><br/>
name:$name <br/><br/>
email:$email<br/><br/>
mobile:$mobile<br/><br/>
messege:$messege</b>";

$mail -> Addattachment('here is problem');

$mail->AddAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
 else{
    echo "mail sent";
  }
 ?>
```

this mail is sent successfully but I want it with attachment. file store in directory is not important. hope this problem solve immediately. thanks in advance because I never learned an used php before.

Comment: Have you tried echo the file path? Could be the attachment was never set to send

Comment: as I say in question I don't know any about php. can you give me example

Comment: ok, please first `echo $filepath;`(attachment) and check the filepath is the right one. (comment the mailing part for this)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: filepath in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\new ab\sendresume.PHP on line 66

Comment: Wait `$mail -> Addattachment($filepath);` ... this is what I mean with `$filepath`: the path where is your attachment (sorry for late response)

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) and base your code on [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example to send attachment using `PHPMailer` class:

http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/a-simple-example-sending-email-with-attachment-using-phpmailer/

Comment: @emrah this forum is to help so, just share with me what are you trying?

Comment: That page is quite out of date and will have problems with the current PHPMailer. The examples and docs provided with PHPMailer are more comprehensive and up to date.